# SwiftUI Charts BarMark aligning annotation to top of chart

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, healthkit

I'm trying out Swifts Charts. I am trying to align the annotation to the top of the chart, but I am not able to do it.

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:
[image]

But this is done with `HStack` on top of the chart, and it does not align 100%. So instead I am using the annotations modifier. The result is this:

[image]

But as you can see, the values are directly on top of the bar, which is not the result I am looking for.

The code used for the annotations is here:

```
.annotation {
   Text("\(Int(item.price))")
     .font(.system(size: 8))
     .rotationEffect(.degrees(270))
     .padding()
 }
```

I have tried to add in a `VStack`, put in the `Text` and a `Spacer` underneath, but that did not help. I also tried with:

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
```

But that did not help either.

Hope you guys can help me you here :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .bottom)` which gives you an annotation overlay over the mark that starts at the bottom of the mark.

[image]

Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let data: [(Int, Int)] = {
        (0...20).map { ($0, Int.random(in: 0...500)) }
    }()

    @State private var selectedX = 6
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Chart {
                ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    let (x,y) = data[i]
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("x", x),
                        y: .value("y", y)
                    )
                    .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
                        Text("\(y)")
                            .font(.system(size: 8))
                            .frame(width: 570 , alignment: .trailing)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                    }
                }
            }
            .chartXScale(domain: 0...20)
            .chartYScale(domain: 0...550)
            .chartYAxis(.hidden)
            .frame(height: 300)
         
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped! :D One thing to keep in mind, for others that might stumble upon this is: the width defined for the text actually defines how far from the bottom it is, so you can play with that to get the look you need :)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right :) That's also why I put in `.chartYScale(domain: 0...550)` with 550 being larger than the max y value of 500, to create space above the bars for the annotation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. It doesn't matter what .frame parameters I use, the annotation always moves depending on the bar size. I can't get them all to align independently of the bar size.